# Table template help

Tags: tables, templates

I am trying to do a similar table in latex but I'm not finding any good source that can help me. How can I write the code so that the mean and variance can look like that. Any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Hope it helps

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \hline
          &       & Parameter & Standard Error \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \multirow{7}[2]{*}{Mean} & Const & 0.446 & 0.088 \bigstrut[t]\\
          & ED    & 0.0751 & 0.0063 \\
          & EX    & 0.0278 & 0.0041 \\
          & EX2   & -0.000332 & 0.00087 \\
          & FE    & -0.277 & 0.033 \\
          & NONWH & -0.138 & 0.053 \\
          & UNION & 0.224 & 0.036 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}[2]{*}{Variance} & Const & -3.64 & 0.36 \bigstrut[t]\\
          & ED    & 0.0699 & 0.0254 \\
          & EX    & 0.0747 & 0.185 \\
          & EX2   & -0.00121 & 0.0004 \\
          & UNION & 0.0738 & 0.132 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Also, add this to your preamble

```
\usepackage{bigstrut}
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since both entries in the first column should be vertically centered with respect to an odd number of rows, there is no need for `\multirow`. In the following MWE, I modified the [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593004/134144) and additionally used horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package as well as `S` type columns from the `siunitx` package in order to align the numbers in the last two columns with respect to the decimal marker:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \sisetup{group-digits=false}
    \begin{tabular}{llS[table-format=-1.6] S[table-format=1.6]}
    \toprule
             &       & {Parameter} & {Standard Error} \\
    \midrule
             & Const & 0.446       & 0.088   \\
             & ED    & 0.0751      & 0.0063  \\
             & EX    & 0.0278      & 0.0041  \\
     Mean    & EX2   & -0.000332   & 0.00087 \\
             & FE    & -0.277      & 0.033   \\
             & NONWH & -0.138      & 0.053   \\
             & UNION & 0.224       & 0.036   \\
    \midrule
             & Const & -3.64       & 0.36    \\
             & ED    & 0.0699      & 0.0254  \\
    Variance & EX    & 0.0747      & 0.185   \\
             & EX2   & -0.00121    & 0.0004  \\
             & UNION & 0.0738      & 0.132   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```